# plot selected indices in different color using matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, subplot

I am trying to plot the error signal. The plot should be in black color when error is zero. It should be in red color whenever there is an error. I am catching the indices with error in an array excdIdx. 
My goal is plot the error indices in red and non-error indices in black. For some reason the for loop is not working.

ErrAxis is the axis
excdIdx contains the list of indices to be plotted inred

```
    h(8) = subplot(plotCount,1,ErrAxis);
    hold off;
    if excdIdx > 0

        plot(time(1:excdIdx),Output(1:excdIdx) - trueSignal(1:excdIdx),'k-'); hold on;

       %this method to plot the error indices in red is not working
       % for elem = 1: size(excdIdx, 2)
       %     index_1 = excdIdx(elem);
       %     index_2 = excdIdx(elem+1);
       %     plot(time(index_1:index_1+1),Output(index_1:index_1+1) - trueSignal(index_1:index_1+1),'r-'); hold on;
       % end 

    else
        plot(time,Output - trueSignal,'k-'); hold on;
    end
```

Comment: Could you please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you're plotting individual data point, I think you should use `scatter`. Try the following code:

```
h(8) = subplot(plotCount,1,ErrAxis);
hold off;
if excdIdx > 0
    scatter(time(1:excdIdx),Output(1:excdIdx) - trueSignal(1:excdIdx),'markerfacecolor','k'); hold on;
    for elem = 1: size(excdIdx, 2)
        index_1 = excdIdx(elem);
        index_2 = excdIdx(elem+1);
        scatter(time(index_1:index_1+1),Output(index_1:index_1+1) - trueSignal(index_1:index_1+1),'markerfacecolor','r');
    end
else 
    scatter(time,Output - trueSignal,'markerfacecolor','k'); hold on;
end
```